# Resharper 10 Ultimate Test Runner changes test directory

Tags: resharper, test-runner

I have opened a bug with Jetbrains but I am hoping that posting in SO will get more visibility.

Instead of running the test from the bin\debug directory, the directory is being changed to: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs12`

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2 Build 104.0.20151218.120627
ReSharper 10.0.20151218.130009

The current workaround I have is:

1. uninstalling ReSharper version 10
2. [uninstall NUnit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885600/jetbrains-resharper-9-ultimate-test-runner-error-nunit-core-unsupportedframewor)
3. Install [ReSharper version 9.2](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-)
4. installing [NUnit Version 2.6.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.4).

Here is the bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-453391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use CurrentDirectory in tests? If so, please refer to [NUnit 3.0 Breaking-Changes page](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Breaking-Changes):

> CurrentDirectory No longer set to the directory containing the test
>   assembly. Use TestContext.TestDirectory to locate that directory.

Comment: Within the class that I am testing, I have the code:
var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
I am guessing this is bad.  I think I should use a static path.

Comment: Per Charlie Pool: "This is by design, as shown here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Breaking-Changes

In earlier versions, NUnit changed the working directory. It no longer does so. You can use TestContext.TestDirectory to get the directory that contains the test assembly."

https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1072

Comment: `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` to be precise