# Resharper 2016.1.2 NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException with NUnit 3 test

Tags: resharper, nunit-3.0

With the latest version of Resharper (2016.1.2) and Visual Studio 2015, I get a "NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException" error when trying to run NUnit 3.2.1 tests.

The error is:
[image: Resharper NUnit runner error]

From the details, it seems to always try to use the 2.6 runner (`[...]\nUnit\Runner26\Src[...]`)

The `Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> Unit Testing -> Enable NUnit3x support` option is checked. The `Enable NUnit 2x support` is not (but checking it has no effect, I tried all combinations.)

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Resharper, but I get the same error.

**Any idea how to fix this?**

It seems to be the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885600/jetbrains-resharper-9-ultimate-test-runner-error-nunit-core-unsupportedframewor), but with a newer version of Resharper.

Versions:

- JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2  Build 105.0.20160522.80219
- Visual Studio 2015 (Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2)

## Edit

A colleague has the same versions of Resharper and VS2015 and it works... the error must be in an upgrade operation from the past 2-3 Resharper that left something on disk and the uninstall did not remove...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed NUnit 3.2.1 from [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download)
I then configured Resharper to use a custom NUnit installation

Resharper -> options -> use specific custom NUnit -> {C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console}

Resharper has detected the NUnit installation and the tests work.

That's after I uninstalled and reinstalled Resharper 2016.1.2 Ultimate with no change in the described behavior.

[image]